# Handling validation error of a JSON payload in Spring RabbitListener

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Let's take the following consumer method for a RabbitMQ queue. Ths payload received from the queue is in JSON format, so I register a bean returning a `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`. This basically works fine.

Now I'd like to add a validation of the `QueueResponse` object, similar to when using Jackson in a `@RestController`, e.g. if the JSON field does not exist or contains an invalid value. In this case, I'd like the code to execute the `catch` block, i.e. throwing an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.

Thus, I added `@Payload @Valid` as described [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#rabbit-validation). But I don't know what to do in the `validationErrorHandler` method. I don't understand the return statement from the documentation. What would I need to do there to reach the `catch` block?

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE_NAME, messageConverter = "jackson2MessageConverter", errorHandler="validationErrorHandler")
public void consume(@Payload @Valid QueueResponse queueResponse) {
    try {
        processMessage(queueResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jackson2MessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
}

// Not sure what to do here...
@Bean
public RabbitListenerErrorHandler validationErrorHandler() {
    return (m, e) -> {
        ...
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error handler exits normally, the message will be acknowledged (discarded).

If the error handler throws an exception, the message will either be requeued (and redelivered) or discarded (and optionally sent to a dead letter queue), depending on the exception type, container properties, and queue arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I do in the `RabbitListenerErrorHandler` is the following:

- check how many times I requeued a message by looking into the `count` property in the `x-death` header
- then decide to either requeue the message by throwing an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` or not. In this last case, instead of just discard the message, send it to a parking-lot exchange (bound to a queue with no consumer, in my case these queues are monitored externally) with additional information (for instance the stack trace of the last failure)